# Very slow perl script execution time

Tags: linux, performance, perl, debian

I have a perl program (`/usr/bin/ckbcomp`) executing very slowly on a freshly installed debian v8 server. I found it while debugging its very long boot time.

I compared the execution of this same script on another server not having this problem and I ended up with the result that they have the exact kernel space execution and that the problem seems to come from the userland code, the one written in perl.

```
# slow execution
$ uptime
14:54:16 up  3:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
$ time ckbcomp -backspace bs -model pc105 us
real    0m1.927s
user    0m1.900s
sys     0m0.016s

# normal execution
$ uptime
14:49:31 up 12 days, 17:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.09
$ time ckbcomp -backspace bs -model pc105 us
real    0m0.381s
user    0m0.376s
sys     0m0.000s
```

You can see the time is spent in user space. The `strace` output is mostly the same and confirms the `time` output (same number of syscalls, same overhead and almost same time spent in kernel space). `uptime` is used to show you the cpu load, so this is not an overload problem.

So I assume the problem comes from the perl execution itself and `ltrace` mostly confirms it, giving `1.710485 seconds` spent in `perl_run()`.

I have now no idea how to further debug the perl program on debian v8. A ltrace-like solution should be good enough to understand where the time is spent.

The perl interpreter is the same on both machines. Maybe it comes from installed libraries...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Google "perl profiler" and look at some of the profiling packages out there for perl...

Comment: couldn't it be a hardware problem? Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't answer directly, because I don't have that script on my system.

However in general - you should be looking at that perl, and see what it's doing.

I would take as a start point - `strace` as you mention that already. `strace -fTt` will follow over forks, so should report the syscalls being made by the perl as well.

However if that doesn't do the trick - `Devel::NYTProf` will be able to tell you a fair amount about how your code is running and what it's doing (and where it's spending its time). Run that, then inspect the bits of code that are being sluggish.